# How to assemble large sparse matrices effectively in python/scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I am working on an FEM project using Scipy. Now my problem is, that
the assembly of the sparse matrices is too slow. I compute the
contribution of every element in dense small matrices (one for each
element). For the assembly of the global matrices I loop over all
small dense matrices and set the matrice entries the following way:

```
[i,j] = someList[k][l]
Mglobal[i,j] = Mglobal[i,j] + Mlocal[k,l]
```

`Mglobal` is a lil_matrice of appropriate size, `someList` maps the
indexing variables.

Of course this is rather slow and consumes most of the matrice
assembly time. Is there a better way to assemble a large sparse matrix
from many small dense matrices? I tried scipy.weave but it doesn't
seem to work with sparse matrices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I posted my response to the scipy mailing list; stack overflow is a bit easier
to access so I will post it here as well, albeit a slightly improved version.

The trick is to use the IJV storage format. This is a trio of three arrays
where the first one contains row indicies, the second has column indicies, and
the third has the values of the matrix at that location. This is the best way
to build finite element matricies (or any sparse matrix in my opinion) as access
to this format is really fast (just filling an an array).

In scipy this is called `coo_matrix`; the class takes the three arrays as an
argument. It is really only useful for converting to another format (CSR os
CSC) for fast linear algebra.

For finite elements, you can estimate the size of the three arrays by something
like

```
size = number_of_elements * number_of_basis_functions**2
```

so if you have 2D quadratics you would do number_of_elements * 36, for example.
This approach is convenient because if you have local matricies you definitely
have the global numbers and entry values: exactly what you need for building
the three IJV arrays. Scipy is smart enough to throw out zero entries, so
overestimating is fine.

Comment: @cp3028: Note that you don't need to do any summing manually using coo_matrix, you can have several entries referring to the same element which will be summed when converted to another format.  See: http://scipy-lectures.github.com/advanced/scipy_sparse/coo_matrix.html

Comment: Hi David,thank you very much for your help. The usage of COO matrices resulted in a speedup by over one magnitude!